# Selecting a column other than select column in sharepoint connected webparts

Tags: connected-web-parts

I have 2 list webparts connected on a page. Selecting a row from ListA will filter the rows from List B. But the problem is, i have to use select icon to do the selection of row from ListA. is it possible to have the selection of rows on some hyperlink column?

Answer (score 0):

I think  you could do that.

1. Hide list A (put custom css to hide web part)
2. Create javascript that will overwrite value of one column in list B that upon clicking it will select row in the connected webPart. (using console for js in Chrome you can catch the right event and wire your javascript accordingly)